# Prevent hero image from stretching on larger screens

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need help preventing my hero image from stretching on larger screens. It's probably a simple fix but I can't seem to make it happen.

It works fine when I make the screen smaller and on mobile as it reduces with flexbox.

Here's a screenshot of the image:

[image]

[image]

```css
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: #222222;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  /* padding: 20px 50px; */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  gap: 50px;
  /* background-image: url('../images/elvis.jpeg'); */
  /* opacity: 50%; */
}

.movie-details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bg-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.banner-img {
  opacity: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="bg-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="banner-img" />
  </div>

  <div class="movie-details">
    <h1>Movie Title</h1>
    <p>Movie overview.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show rendered HTML and CSS for a question like this. It has nothing to do with React.

Comment: I converted your snippet to something closer. Please revise further to show the problem.

Comment: What do you need me to add?

Answer (score 0):

Add [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) to `.banner-image` to control the image's anchor point around which it scales. I think you probably want object-position: center top; or maybe object-position: left top;

```css
.banner-img {
  opacity: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  object-position: center top;
}
```

---

(Original Answer)

Add a `max-width` and set horizontal margins to `auto` to center it.

```css
.hero {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It creates white borders on the sides

Comment: It's exposing the area around/behind the hero block because it's no longer stretching, which is what I thought you were asking for. (If you don't want it to stretch, what is the desired behavior with regard to the area no longer filled by the stretched hero?)

Comment: Ah I see, that's my bad maybe I didn't explain properly. I just need it to fit the screen without the image looking stretched as you can see in the photo

Comment: The image doesn't appear stretched to me, if by stretched we mean "scaled without maintaining the aspect ratio". If you don't want to clip his head you could set `top: 0` on the image so it grows down from the top instead of out from the center.

Comment: Yes you're correct. Its not stretched but doesn't seem to fit. I have attached what the photo is supposed to look like. You should be able to see!

Comment: Ignore my comment above where I said to set `top: 0`. I misread how you were including the image so I don't think that's going to help. I need to step away for a bit but I'll check in again later.

Comment: Add [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) to `.banner-image` to control how the image scales. I think you probably want `object-fit: center top;` or maybe `object-fit: left top;`

Comment: Updated my answer to the `object-position` suggestion. (And in the comment above I meant `object-position`, not `object-fit`. (Ugh. Oops. Sorry.))

Comment: Tiny bit stretched but much better, thanks!